# Submit multidimensional arrays POST corrupt

Tags: php, html, apache, multidimensional-array, zend-server

I encountered a strange problem and i really don't have any idea why this happens.

Taking this form:

```
<?php
print_r($_POST);
?>
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
    <form action="" method="post">
            <input type="text" name="hello[a][b][c]" value="d"/>
            <input type="submit"/>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

When i submit a form with multidimensional arrays within, on one server, i reads it as this:

```
Array ( 
    [hello] => Array ( 
        [0] => 
    ) 
)
```

On the other server, i get this:

```
Array ( 
    [hello] => Array ( 
        [a] => Array ( 
            [b] => Array ( 
                [c] => d 
            ) 
        ) 
    ) 
)
```

Below are the server environment details:

> Server One: Ubuntu 14.04-TLS, PHP 5.5.9.1 and Apache 2.4.7-1ubuntu4.1
>   0 
>  Server Two: Debian 7, PHP/5.5.13 ZendServer/7.0.0,
>   Apache/2.2.22 (Debian)

Does someone know this issue or has any ideas?

Kind regards,
Christian

Comment: I'd look at the php.ini's. There must be something in the php configurations. I've not see the first example output before.

Comment: Are you sure you tested the same scripts? There is no reason for `[0]` in the Ubuntu server.

Comment: Good issue, could show the settings using php_info?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the issue..

The first server was accessed via DNS redirect. 
Client -> www.x.com -> www.z.com (Server). 
Both domains were from different companies. 
The second one was accessed directly. 
So after calling the form on www.z.com, it worked as always.
The redirect wasn't configured as an A-record. When it was, it worked without problems.

Comment: Upvote for taking dns configuration into consideration